# Unit testing examples for APIs in Django Rest Framework for GET and DELETE

Tags: django, unit-testing, django-rest-framework

I am using Django Rest Framework and I am trying to write the unit tests for api methods inside views.py file.Here is http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/testing/#example given a  example   But I have no idea to write unit tests for api views with GET and DELETE
Here are my api views:

views.py

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def getAllCustomers(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        k = Customer.objects.all()
        serializer = CustomerSerializer(k, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)


@api_view(['DELETE'])
def deleteCustomer(request, pk):
    try:
        k = Customer.objects.get(pk=pk)
    except Customer.DoesNotExist:
        return HttpResponse(status=404)

    if request.method == 'DELETE':
        k.delete()
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

URLS.PY

```
url(r'^Customer/$', getAllCustomers, name='getAllCustomers'),
url(r'^Customer/del/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)$', deleteCustomer, name='deleteCustomer'),
```

Thanks To All!

Comment: def test_delete_Klient(self):
        k = Customer.objects.get(pk=1)
        client = APIClient()
        response = client.delete("/Customer/del/")
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 204)

Comment: And this doesnt work because?

Comment: client = APIClient()
        response = client.delete("/Customer/del/1")
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 204)                                 and the result                                                                                                  Failure
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\erik\Desktop\untitled\balt\tests.py", line 45, in test_deleteCustomer
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 204)
AssertionError: 404 != 204

Comment: Okay, so there was no customers in your database.